# Copy tables from one server to another in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 X, table2 C, table3 M, table4 XSDT
WHERE X.CATID= C.CATID
AND M.MEMID= X.MEMID
AND XSDT.SHIPDISC= X.SHIPDISC;
```

Say I want to run this query on the HOST db (external) and get its data and copy it to a local DB2 database.

Is there a way to do so in DB2?

I know teradata has fastload... but I'm not sure about db2 or how I would go about doing so.

Please keep in mind I *do not* have dba-level privileges.

Solution to this: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0002079.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this with SQL, then you would use something like the following SQL:

```
create table schema2.table1;

insert into schema2.table1 
    select * from schema1.table1;
```

Since you're joining tables, you would have to define the local table in your CREATE TABLE SQL and list the columns in your INSERT as well as your SELECT.

You can do a DB2 backup of the tables, and restore them to your local schema.

You can do a DB2 export of the tables, and use DB2 import to create them on your local schema.

You can use the DB2 db2move utility.

Comment: Can you show an example of DB2 db2move utility, and DB2 export? Also does DB2 export physically move everything out of the original tables?

Comment: The DB2 manuals for DB2 version 9 are located here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp  DB2 export makes a copy of the data in the table(s).